# Шрифты в android

Tags: android, шрифты, java

Возможно ли как нибудь запилить шрифт для текствьюшек в формате `pfb`?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще сторонний шрифт можно подтянуть из `assets`

```
final Typeface digitalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font.TTF");
```

и повесить на Ваш текст вью

```
textView.setTypeface(digitalFont);
```

если с `pfb` не прокатит, попробуйте сконвертировать его в `TTF` вот [этим](http://www.freefontconverter.com/).